# Maths Rules in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, math

I'm trying to depreciate the value of an item in a straight line over time

If I use `itemValue2 = itemvalue1 - itemvalue1*item-Age/item-Life`, It works perfectly BUT when I originally

used     `itemValue2 = itemvalue1 * ( 1 - item-Age/item-Life)` it constantly evaluated to `itemValue1` .

Why would this be ? is it the type of the number 1 ?

`itemValue1` and `itemValue2` are Doubles, `item-Age` and `item-Life` are Longs

Or is it some maths rule that I haven't understood?

Comment: Since `item Age` and `item Life` are integers, the result of `item Age/item Life` is also an integer (integer division) and assuming that `item Age` < `item Life`, the result will be `0`.

Comment: I have trouble parsing your code. Is `item Age` actually Kotlin syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, `Longs` that divide will result in a truncated `Long` value. If your resulting value would've been been less than 1, then the result is a truncated value of 0. That leaves `itemValue1` to be multiplied by 1, which is itself. You will have to cast to number types that use decimals without truncating like `Double` or `Float`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a basic principle that I had not learnt. I will remember that!

Answer (score -1):

This thing called Mathematical precedence in kotlin, mean when you create operation like this `1+2*3` the expected result is `9` but not, `7` is the result, in kotlin be the priority for the multiply's `*` and the divide's `/` then came the plus `+` and minus `-`.

To resolve this issue you need to add the brackets `()` it's had priority before any operation symbol in the language.

And the operation will be `(1+2)*3`it will gave result `9`.

Comment: In a way, precedence IS the problem. If I had kept the decimal value involved, instead of allowing the two longs to divide as a separate element and truncate,  all would have been well